Pointer to lvalue/rvalue
Suppose that you have a struct which has a member, and also has operator* which forwards access to this member while maintaining the value category:
struct Bar {
    void func() & {
        printf("func() &\n");
    }
    void func() && {
        printf("func() &&\n");
    }
};

struct Foo {
    Bar bar;

    Bar &operator*() & {
        return bar;
    }
    Bar &&operator*() && {
        return static_cast<Bar &&>(bar);
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;

    (*foo).func();   // prints func() &
    (*Foo()).func(); // prints func() &&
}

Now, let's add operator-> to Foo, so it is easier to call func():
struct Foo {
    // ...

    Bar *operator->() & {
        return &bar;
    }

    // this should return "pointer to rvalue Bar"
    Bar *operator->() && {
        return &bar;
    }
};

The problem is, there is no such thing as pointer to lvalue/rvalue, so both of these call the lvalue func() &:
int main() {
    Foo foo;

    foo->func();   // prints func() &
    Foo()->func(); // prints func() &
}

I have two questions, a practical and a theoretical one:

is it possible to have an operator-> somehow which maintains value category just like operator* does it, while keeping the same calling syntax?
isn't this a hole of C++'s the type system?

(Note, a similar type to Foo, std::optional has the same behavior.)

Question is interesting as curiosity, but from practical point of view I do not see a real life use-case of Bar *operator->() &&. Smart pointer which moves away its content when operator -> is used?

Even if there would be a use case for  Bar &&operator*() && { this implementation would be highly surprising, when using -> nobody would expect an rvalue reference. That's what std::move is for

AFAIK a pointer does not differentiate/hold the value category of what it points to, so I don't think it's possible. But as others pointed, I don't really see the need of that (that doesn't mean there is not though)

@MarekR: I mentioned std::optional. I think it makes sense that std::optional<YourType>()->func() calls the rvalue func variant, just like YourType().func() and (*std::optional<YourType>()).func() calls the rvalue variant. If there is a use case for YourType().func(), then that is a use case for std::optional<YourType>()->func() as well.

@geza I'm not fully sure if I could agree on that last argument. std::optional<yourType>() would build an empty optional, calling ->func() on would fail anyway. OK, it might be the return value of a function. But wouldn't one in that case have to check if there's a value contained at all before? So we'd need to store the value somewhere anyway to do so, and the rvalue gets an lvalue…

To get a pointer to an object we need to take the address of. How meaningful is taking the address of r-values anyway?

@Aconcagua: yeah, I was sloppy there, I meant YourType(...).func() vs. std::optional<YourType>(std::in_place, ...).func(). But note, don't take this example exactly as it is. The point is, if one has an rvalue YourType, and YourType has an rvalue func(), and it is a use case, then having an rvalue std::optional<YourType> calling the rvalue ->func() is a use case as well.

@Aconcagua: I don't understand your comment. In Bar *operator->() &&, I take the address of bar, there is no problem there (bar is an lvalue "locally", but at the "outside world", it is actually a member of a prvalue). The problem is that by this step (taking the address), the value category is lost.

I think it's more correct to say that the value category is not lost, but I cannot return a type which has the desired value category.

@geza Well, locally it's not an r-value, but at a wider scope to take the address of you use the address of a r-value (this!) and add an address to. In sense of meaningfulness, is there much of (if any at all) a difference in taking the address of an r-value or the address of a member of?

Hmm… Seeking for a meaningful use case one might come up with Baz b = Foo()->baz() with baz being overloaded correspondingly returning either a l- or a r-value reference again, which would avoid having to write b = std::move(Foo()->baz());. That actually appears somehow meaningful to me, the local would be destroyed anyway, so why not take out members of it? Still wondering if one might not rather have an overloaded bar() function returning references instead of the operators. Original expression leaves a strange feeling to me at least.

@Aconcagua: sure, with references things work. The question is what happens with operator->. It's common that classes have this, and it seems that operator-> may have incorrect behavior. If one sees an expression (*get_optional()).func(), then one might wonder why it is not written like this: get_optional()->func(). But this shouldn't rewritten like this blindly, because it may alter behavior. This is unexpected, as it is common to think about (*x). and x-> as equivalents. But in this case, they are not. If operator-> allowed to return references, then this problem didn't exist.

@geza That's actually a good point (the inequivalence) – and actually returning a reference for operator-> always would have felt more natural to me (meaning for many years now...), considering that with native operator-> the expression pointer->member isn't a pointer either...

There is no such thing as "pointer to rvalue Bar". Dereferencing a pointer is always an lvalue.
However, you can fake this, with major caveats; It can only affect member functions of Bar, can't differ in return types, and only with the co-operation of Bar. Data members accessed Foo{}->member will still be lvalues.
You can return a non-pointer type from operator->, and it's operator-> will be called, continuing until you get to a pointer type.
template <typename T>
struct rvalue_proxy
{
    rvalue_proxy(T* ptr) : ptr(ptr) { ptr->fake_rvalue = true; }
    ~rvalue_proxy() { ptr->fake_rvalue = false; }

    T * operator->() { return ptr; }
    T * ptr;
};

struct Bar {
    void func() & {
        if (fake_rvalue)
            printf("func() &&\n");
        else
            printf("func() &\n");
    }
    void func() && {
        printf("func() &&\n");
    }
private:
    bool fake_rvalue = false;
    friend class rvalue_proxy<Bar>;
};

struct Foo {
    Bar bar;

    Bar &operator*() & {
        return bar;
    }
    Bar &&operator*() && {
        return static_cast<Bar &&>(bar);
    }

    Bar *operator->() & {
        return &bar;
    }

    rvalue_proxy<Bar> operator->() && {
        return { &bar };
    }
};

As to your theoretical question: This is not a hole in the C++ type system, as value category is a property of expressions, separate from type. It is a hole in expressiveness, as member access is only overloadable through operator->, and that has to involve a pointer somewhere.

And if return values of the two func overloads differ? Does not in question, sure, but I think it targets rather the general case...

@Aconcagua yes, added that to the caveats
